# C# .Net How to read exception stack to know what exception to catch

Tags: .net, exception

Ok, I'm trying to add Exception Handling to a program based on a history of errors that have occurred.  But I'm struggling with exactly what Exception I should actually "catch".  I've listed 3 different exceptions below, 2 of them are really the same but I'm guessing different .net version have different verbosity to the exceptions.

Is there a "good" way to read these and know what exception to catch.  In the 3rd example it lists CommunciationException, WebException, IOException and SocketException so which one should be used to catch this and react to it.  Experience has shown me that CommunicationException is too broad and covers too many exceptions that I DON'T want to catch.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

and this:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

or this:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://webaddress/WebServices/webservice.asmx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: They all look like `CommunicationException`s to me.  Why don't you want to catch that exception?  If there are "too many exceptions" that sounds like an entirely different problem.

Comment: There are many other exceptions that inheirit from CommunicationException like FaultException and others that are not a result of a slow or dropped connection.  But again my question is really how to read and identity the "real" exception.